# LTO3 tape drive with Adaptec 2940U2W on Ubuntu Server 16. Is it possible to feed it data fast enough with this combo?

Tags: 16.04, server, backup, scsi

Been playing around with tape backup for a while now and have been unable to make any headway in getting my LTO3 drive to work at full speed.

I am using an HP Ultirum 960, an Adaptec 2940U2W and running Ubuntu Server 16 LTS on an old Xeon board. I am able to push data to the tape but at very slow speeds (the drive writes a chunk and spins down while it waits for more).

As I understand it you have to push data fast enough or the drive will fill it's cache, spin up and write it, then spin down while it waits for more data making backup really, really slow.

I purchased the 2940U2W as I had an older model which was rated at slower speeds. This card claims 80MB/s and from my googling as long as I hit 27MB/s the drive should run at full speed but I am getting the same speed (around 16MB/s) as I did on my previous SCSI card. Also with this card there is no "CTRL+A" option at boot as there was on the older one, so I cant see any settings the card's bios. Regardless, is this card even fit for driving an LTO3 tape drive?

I know very little about any of this is I am honest, I am a Linux noob, entirely self taught and I know nothing about tape storage.

Setting up this Ubunutu server is my first real experience using Linux on a regular basis and figuring this one out has defeated me! I am sure I am overlooking / not understanding something real basic...

If you have any experience with tape backups on a similar set up please advise and let me know if you need any specific info.

Thank you for reading, sorry it was so long and I look forward to any input at all on my issue!

Comment: This is probably a hardware issue. The sweet spot is indeed around 27 MB/s. The  BIOS should be at Ultra 160. Plus you need a cable that supports ultra 160 and it should IDEALLY be 1m/3ft or shorter. 12m/40ft is possible but it will decrease the speed quickly (but as long as you do not go under that 27Mb/s it will work).

Comment: Cable I have is real short, like 30cm. The card says Ultra 2 LVD/SE on the port so is that enough to hit that throughput?

I am unable to get into the bios of the card to change settings as it does not display one at boot (mobo bios is set to "display addin card text" or however it is phrased and still no luck)

From what I have seen it is possible to disable bios on the card from Windows software. Is there a way to turn it back on, a jumper reset maybe on the card, or linux software?

Otherwise I do have a Windows 98 Machine I can chuck it in and see if I can configure it there.